# Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: function-construction

Is there a way to evaluate a string containing RPN in Mathematica?

SE thinks this question is too short, so let me expand on it.
Do you know of any function, that provides the following functionality?

```
EvalRPN["5 4 + 3 /"]
```

> 3

Or even symbolically?

```
EvalRPN["a b + c /"]
```

> (a+b)/c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing is, you need to identify what operators should be infix, what should be prefix, what should be postfix, and how many elements from the stack to use. There may be a better way than just listing them, but here I just list them and then use `ToExpression` to make functions out of them to apply to already-evaluated stack elements (e.g. `ToExpression["#1" <> op <> "#2&"]`). Anything that's not a listed operator is simply evaluated and put on the stack.

```
rpn`infix = {"+", "-", "*", "\[Times]", "/", "\[Divide]", "^", ".", 
   "==", "\[Equal]", "!=", "\[NotEqual]", "<", ">", "<=", 
   "\[LessEqual]", ">=", "\[GreaterEqual]", "&&", "||"};
rpn`prefix = {"Sqrt", "CubeRoot", "Log", "Log10", "Log2", "Exp", 
   "Sin", "Cos", "Tan", "ArcSin", "ArcCos", "ArcTan", "Sinh", "Cosh", 
   "Tanh", "ArcSinh", "ArcCosh", "ArcTanh", "N", "Abs", "Arg", "Re", 
   "Im", "Round", "Floor", "Ceiling", "IntegerPart", "FractionalPart",
    "Gamma", "Erf", "Erfc", "InverseErf", "InverseErfc"};
ArcTan2[y_, x_] := ArcTan[x, y]
rpn`prefix2 = {"Mod", "Quotient", "GCD", "LCM", "Binomial", "Surd", 
   "ArcTan2"};
rpn`prefixall = {"Plus", "Times", "Min", "Max"};
rpn`postfix = {"!"};
rpn::short = "`1` ignored -- needs `2` entries on the stack";
rpn[stack_, {op_, rest___}] :=
 Which[
  MemberQ[rpn`infix, op],
  If[Length[stack] < 2, Message[rpn::short, op, 2]; rpn[stack, {rest}],
   rpn[Append[Drop[stack, -2], 
     ToExpression["#1" <> op <> "#2&"] @@ Take[stack, -2]], {rest}]],
  MemberQ[rpn`prefix, op],
  If[Length[stack] < 1, Message[rpn::short, op, 1]; rpn[stack, {rest}],
   rpn[Append[Drop[stack, -1], ToExpression[op]@stack[[-1]]], {rest}]],
  MemberQ[rpn`prefix2, op],
  If[Length[stack] < 2, Message[rpn::short, op, 2]; rpn[stack, {rest}],
   rpn[Append[Drop[stack, -2], 
     ToExpression[op] @@ Take[stack, -2]], {rest}]],
  MemberQ[rpn`prefixall, op],
  rpn[{ToExpression[op] @@ stack}, {rest}],
  MemberQ[rpn`postfix, op],
  If[Length[stack] < 1, Message[rpn::short, op, 1]; rpn[stack, {rest}],
   rpn[Append[Drop[stack, -1], 
     ToExpression["#" <> op <> "&"]@stack[[-1]]], {rest}]],
  True,
  rpn[Append[stack, ToExpression[op]], {rest}]
  ]
rpneval[str_] := First@rpn[{}, StringSplit[str]]
```

Just for fun, I threw in some that operate on the entire stack, so `Times` multiplies the stack elements together, since you already have `*` to multiply just the bottom two.

You can't have RPN operators with a variable number of arguments (unless the number is implied by the contents of the stack), so I added an `ArcTan2` for a two-argument arctangent.

Examples:

```
rpneval["1 2 + 3 4 + * Exp 10 ! Sqrt 70 42 GCD"]
```

> `{E^21, 720 Sqrt[7], 14}`

Note that the result has to be a list, since the expression might leave more than one thing on the stack. You can always get the bottom of the stack with `Last`:

```
rpneval["a b + c d + * e / n ^"]//Last
```

> `(((a + b) (c + d))/e)^n`

If speed is important, the function lists could be made into a single association.

Answer (score 6):

```
rpn[{}, stackipt_: {}] := First@stackipt
rpn[list_, stack_: {}] := Module[{ops = {Plus, Subtract, Times}}, 
  If[MemberQ[ops, First@list], 
   rpn[Rest@list, Prepend[stack[[3 ;;]], (First@list) @@ stack[[2 ;; 1 ;; -1]]]], 
   rpn[Rest@list, Prepend[stack, First@list]]]]


rpn[{3, 2, 5, Plus, Times}]
(* 21 *)

rpn[{a, b, c, d, Plus, Times, Plus}]
(* a + b (c + d) *)
```

Comment: The OP wants to evaluate a string.

Comment: @MarkAdler Yep, well, I don't think s/he should

Answer (score 5):

A rule based option:

```
Clear[rpn]
$InfixOperators = Plus | Subtract | Times | Divide;
$PrefixOperators = Cos | Sin | Sqrt;
operand = Except@Join[$InfixOperators, $PrefixOperators];

rpn[{a : operand ..., b : operand, c : operand, op : $InfixOperators, d___}] := rpn[{a, op[b, c], d}]
rpn[{a : operand ..., b : operand, op : $PrefixOperators, c___}] := rpn[{a, op[b], c}]
rpn[{res_}] := res
```

Examples:

```
rpn[{a, b, c, d, Plus, Times, Plus}]
```

> `a + b (c + d)`

```
rpn[{a, b, Plus, c, Divide}]
```

> `(a + b)/c`

```
rpn[{4, Sqrt, 5, Plus}]
```

> 7

To evaluate strings:

```
$OperatorNotations = {"+" -> Plus, "-" -> Subtract, "*" -> Times, "/" -> Divide};

EvalRPN[str_] := rpn[StringSplit[str] /. $OperatorNotations // ToExpression]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will take a few seconds to run the first time in a session that an operator is used since it needs to download the `"WolframLanguageSymbol"` `Entity` for that operator. After that subsequent calls in the session with the entity will be fast since it is in the cache.

`getMathOperation` takes the short notation of the operator and returns the symbol.

```
getMathOperation[op_String] := 
 ToExpression[
  CanonicalName@
   First@EntityList@
     Entity["WolframLanguageSymbol", {EntityProperty[
         "WolframLanguageSymbol", "ShortNotations"] -> op}]]
```

`evalRPN` evaluates a reverse polish notation string and makes use of `getMathOperation`.

```
evalRPN[expr_String] :=
 With[{s = StringSplit[expr]},
  Fold[
   Function[{running, next},
    getMathOperation[Last@next][(running), ToExpression@First@next]],
   getMathOperation[s[[3]]][Sequence @@ ToExpression /@ s[[1 ;; 2]]],
   Partition[s[[4 ;;]], 2]]
  ]
```

Testing it out.

```
evalRPN["a b + c /"]
(* (a + b)/c *)

evalRPN["a b + c / e - f ^ g *"]
(* ((a + b)/c - e)^f g *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you're going to use `ToExpression` anyway, then you can just evaluate the operator directly with having to convert it to the symbol for that function.

Comment: Doesn't work on `evalRPN["2 3 + 4 5 + *"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this approach easier,

```
l={"a", "b", "+", "c", "/"}

Polish[q_List] := 
 ReplaceRepeated[
   q, {s___, a_, b_, c_String, 
      d___} /; (c == "+" || c == "/" || c == "*" || 
       c == "/") :> {s, {a, c, b}, d}] //. {a___, {b_String, c_, 
     d_String}, e___} :> {a, b <> c <> d, e}


Polish[l] =>{"a+b/c"}
Polish[{"2", "3", "+", "4", "5", "+", "*"}]=> {"2+3*4+5"}
```

You can convert it into expression by using `ToExpression` if you want.

Comment: Fails on "a b + c d + \*". Gives "a+b\*c+d". I'm seeing this simple case fail on many of the answers here. Am I the only one who uses an HP calculator?

Comment: @MarkAdler : I think its invalid expression. {a,b,+} on stack, poped as a+b, a+b in stack, push c, then push d, then pop c+d, push c+d over a+b, but there is no more operand for these two !!

Comment: Ok, clearly you don't use an HP calculator. a b + leaves a+b on the stack. Then c d + leaves c+d on the stack, under a+b. Then * multiplies the two things on the stack, giving (a+b)(c+d). There is no pushing something "over" something else.